# Removing from the front of a queue, returning option but not for every match

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I had this problem of creating a dequeue operation for

```
type 'a t = 'a list * 'a list
exception Empty
```

The queue is represented as a pair of lists (r,f), where
f is the beginning of the queue [e1, e2, . . . , ei]
and r is the end of the queue [en; en-1; . . . ; ei+1]

And I am asked to define this operation: *`dequeue` returns an option on queue equal to the queue in parameter minus the first element, or None in case of error.*

First of all I don't know what is this *error*.

So, this is what I did:

```
let dequeue (r, f) = 
  match (r, f) with
  | ([], []) -> None
  | (r', _::f') -> Some (r', f')
  | (r'', []) -> Some ([], List.tl (List.rev r''))
```

But the code provided as solution is this:

```
let dequeue (r,f) = 
  match (r,f) with
  | (r,_::q) -> Some (r,q)
  | ([],[]) -> None
  | _ -> ([], try List.tl_exn (List.rev r) with _ -> raise Empty)
```

And it doesn't make sense to me why for the third case there is no `option` being returned, and why in this third case we have to handle exception. `List.tl_exn` will never have empty 'r'. For (r, _::q) can handle ([], [1]) and ([1], [2]), ([], []) can handle the empty queue, and (r'', []) can handle ([1], []) for example, and this last example for the third case, we don't have to raise exception, because `List.tl_exn [1]` will be []. Is this correct? Is the code solution provided buggy or not complete?

Comment: That last line in the second function is rather curious. `f` has been matched against for being a non-empty list, and the `r` pattern means `r` can be either empty or non-empty. The next pattern means if `f` is empty and `r` is empty. The only situation that hasn't been matched is `r` being non-empty and `f` being empty. In that situation, finding the tail of a reversed non-empty list should never raise an exception.

Comment: So you'd prefer my solution over the provided one :D ?

Comment: I think it's silly to use pattern-matching on lists which can identify empty lists, and then worry about accessing the tail of one of those lists and getting an exception.

Comment: @Chris https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75991325/module-ocaml-and-signature-squiggly-lines Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the third result is missing `Some`. Hence the code is wrong. The compiler diagnoses a type error for this reason.

If you add `Some` to the third result, the provided solution looks correct but weirdly coded, as you also say. The third case of the `match` will be taken when the second list (front of queue) is empty but the first list (rear of queue) is nonempty. In this case `List.tl_exn` will always return the tail of the list and will never raise an exception.

It would be more straightforward to replace `List.tl_exn` with `List.tl` and take out the exception handling. The resulting function would have the same behavior.

**Update**

It appears that this code is written for the Jane Street Core library, which has a function named `List.tl_exn`. Furthermore the `List.tl` function returns `'a option` for this library (so I'm told). That's why the code is so unnecessarily complicated. I apologize -- I don't have any experience using Core.

At any rate, the provided code doesn't look so strange if you realize that you can't just use `List.tl` to get the tail of a list. Testing for an exception whenever calling a function that ends with `_exn` might be required by the in-house style rules--even if the exception is impossible.

Here is the fixed code using the unnecessary `Empty` exception:

```
let dequeue (r,f) =
  match (r,f) with
  | (r,_::q) -> Some (r,q)
  | ([],[]) -> None
  | _ -> Some ([], try List.tl_exn (List.rev r) with _ -> raise Empty)
```

Here is fixed code that depends on the exception being impossible:

```
let dequeue (r,f) =
  match (r,f) with
  | (r,_::q) -> Some (r,q)
  | ([], []) -> None
  | _ -> Some ([], List.tl_exn (List.rev r)) (* r <> [] *)
```

Unfortunately I can't test these functions because (as I say) I don't use Core. But they should be pretty close to correct :-)

Comment: But where is the `Some` for the provided solution? Is my solution a complete correct one?

Comment: Whoops good point. I changed my answer a bit, thanks.

Comment: [`List.tl_exn`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/109.20.00/doc/core/List.html#VALtl_exn) in Core. The [`List.tl`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/109.20.00/doc/core/List.html#VALtl) in Core returns an `option` type.

Comment: @Chris This is an interesting point I wanted to know. since I use `List.tl`, should I remove `Some` ? Because the returned `option` is only for the front list in the queue.

Comment: Why? What are the inner workings?

Comment: So this would be correct `  | (r'', []) -> ([], List.tl (List.rev r''))` for my solution? It is confusing to me

Comment: You wat the `Some` around the whole pair. Sorry, this is getting crazy. It is unfortunate that Jane Street libraries have the same names as the standard ones. I iwll add more to my answer.

Comment: This is perfectly valid code with just the Stdlib if you change `List.tl_exn` to `List.tl`.